# Unknown Peer error when trying to run corda on multiple nodes

Tags: corda

I am trying to run corda on multiple nodes. As per this thread - https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/39, I have modifed the node.conf files and started the nodes. (BankA and Notary on machineA, BankB and BankCorda on MachineB) and started all four of them. Till node startup everything is fine.

When I try to run this - `gradlew samples:trader-demo:runBuyer` from machine A, I get the following error on NodeA - `unknown peer - BankOfCorda`
and the
`Notary - [ERROR] 2018-06-01T12:37:22,766 [Node thread] StateMachineManager - Unknown peer C=UK,L=London,OU=corda,O=R3,CN=BankOfCorda in SessionInit(initiatorSessionId=6217119355343956857, flowName=net.corda.flows.NotaryFlow$Client, firstPayload=SignRequest(tx=SignedTransaction(txBits=[14010…], sigs=[[…]], id=xxx)))`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A possible fix below. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have messages queued up in your nodes' message queues when you stop them. After changing the nodes' names and restarting the nodes, the message queues can't find the desired recipients on the network.

You can fix this by deleting each node's `artemis` folder.